# post method array data in php and swift

Tags: php, swift

I am sending array data with post http method, that is, I am sending more than one value. But now I'm getting a blank output. Although I post "formKATID", I get no results. How can I send Array data?

**Swift**

```
 @objc func kategoriSaydır(){
...
   var values: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
        values["formKATID="] = "5" as AnyObject
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: [])
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                                   guard let data = data else {
                                       return
                                   }
... }
```

**PHP**

```
$formKATID = $_POST['formKATID'];

$tsql = "... WHERE KATEGORI.ID IN(".implode(', ',$formKATID).")";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
```

Comment: You don't need the `=` in `formKATID=`.

Comment: When I uninstall it doesn't work again @Wyetro

Comment: What are you uninstalling? Can you confirm that the server is receiving the post?

Comment: I deleted the equals sign. Yes, I can.

Comment: So what happens if you print the dictionary `$_POST`? Which keys do you see?

Comment: How do I print because I sent Array, it won't work?

Comment: `values` is a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary, not an array. I don't use php but there should be a print function so you can see what `$_POST` is equal to.

Answer (score -1):

You're posting a dictionary where the key is `formKATID=` and the value is the string `"5"`. Then in your php code you are looking for the key `formKATID`. Those are not equal, so you will need to remove the `=`.

And if using `URLSession` seems confusing I made a [really basic pod](https://github.com/RyuGames/NetworkUtils) (or use something like Alamorfire) that wraps around it so that all you would need to do is:

```
networkUtils.post(url, dictionary).then { data in
  // Use data response here
}.catch { error in
  // Catch error here
}
```

Comment: Although I have removed the equal sign, it still does not work

Comment: It is equal to KATEGORI.ID in the table. When sending the string value, I send it as follows: let postString = "formKATID=\(dataToUpload)"

Comment: That's not what I meant. After the line `$formKATID = $_POST['formKATID'];`, what is that variable equal to? Is it an empty String or null?. What if you switch the line to `$formKATID = $_POST['formKATID='];`?